# \end{alignat} gives undefined control sequence error

Tags: errors, undefined, alignat

When compiling this code, it returned a pdf with the compiled equations. However, all commands below this chunk would not execute anymore. For the `\end{alignat}`, it returns an undefined control sequence error. Why does this occur? Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{subequations} 
\allowdisplaybreaks[1]
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{alignat}{3}
    & \begin{dcases}
        \sum_{a=1}^{dm}\dfrac{(df_a)}{2}\ \text{als dm even} \\
        \sum_{a=1}^{dm}(df_a)\ \text{als dm oneven}
    \end{dcases}\\
    \text{met}& \nonumber\\
    &M = alt + 1 \nonumber\\
    & \epsilon \text{ is de precisie van de oplossing} \nonumber\\
    \text{onder voorwaarde dat}& \nonumber\\
    &C_j = \sum_{i=1}^{alt}(c_{ij}*i)\ &&\forall j=1,..,alt\\
    & \sum_{i=1}^{alt}(c_{ij}) = 1\ &&\forall j=1,..,alt \\
    & \sum_{j=1}^{alt}(c_{ij}) = 1\ &&\forall i=1,..,alt \\
    &T_{a+1} > T_a\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm-1 \\
    & \sum_{a=1}^{dm}(t_{ab}) = 1\ &&\forall b=1,..,dm \\
    & \sum_{b=1}^{dm}(t_{ab}) = 1\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    &T_b = \sum_{a=1}^{dm}(Tlinear_{ab})\ &&\forall b=1,..,dm \\
    &Tlinear_{ab} \leq t_{ab}*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm; b=1,..,dm \\
    &Tlinear_{ab} \geq - t_{ab}*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm; b=1,..,dm \\
    &Tlinear_{ab} \leq fi_a + (1-t_{ab})*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm; b=1,..,dm \\
    &Tlinear_{ab} \geq fi_a - (1-t_{ab})*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm; b=1,..,dm \\
    &C_j \geq C_i + M*(gc_{ij} - 1)\ &&\forall i=1,..,alt-1; j=i+1,..,alt \\
    &C_i \geq C_j - M*gc_{ij}\ &&\forall i=1,..,alt-1; j=i+1,..,alt \\
    &fi_{a} = 1+ \dfrac{2\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{alt}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{alt-1} (2gc_{ij}-1)*g_{aij}}{alt^2-alt} &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    &W_b = \sum_{a=1}^{dm}(Wlinear_{ab})\ &&\forall b=1,..,dm \\
    &Wlinear_{ab} \leq t_{ab}*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm; b=1,..,dm \\
    &Wlinear_{ab} \geq -t_{ab}*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm; b=1,..,dm \\
    &Wlinear_{ab} \leq w_a + (1-t_{ab})*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm; b=1,..,dm \\
    &Wlinear_{ab} \geq w_a - (1-t_{ab})*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm; b=1,..,dm \\
    &CW_{a} = \sum_{b=1}^{a}{W_b}\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    &CW_{a} - M*d_a \leq 0.5-\epsilon \ &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    &CW_{a} + (1-d_a)*M \geq 0.5\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    &df_a \leq med_a*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    &df_a \geq -med_a*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    &df_a \leq T_a + (1-med_{a})*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    &df_{a} \geq T_{a} - (1-med_{a})*M\ &&\forall a=1,..,dm \\
    & \sum_{a=1}^{dm}(a*med_{a}) = dm + 1 - \sum_{a=1}^{dm}d_{a}\\
    & \sum_{a=1}^{dm} med_{a} = 1
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}%
```

Comment: do not show code snippets. Always make a small but complete example, that makes testing and debugging much easier.

Comment: You're using `dcases` did you remember to load `mathtools`? This is why Ulrike asks for a full minimal example. BTW, i'd write `b=1,\dotsc,dm`

Comment: I get no error once I load `mathtools` and add a `document` environment.

Comment: the actual error message (which you have not shown) does show which command is undefined.

Comment: I think i found what the problem is in. The subequations environment would count subequations as 1.a, 1.b, 1.c, ... The problem arose once i tried adding a 27th equation, hence when no letters in the alphabet are left to number them. How could I still number them when having more than 26 equations?

Comment: no that would not give an undefined command error (you could use `\roman` rather than `\alph` for example if you want to go past 26,